# How do I alter an excel sheet depending on selection in form control combo box?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

So what I want is to have my sheet look distinct ways depending on which of 3 options i select in a format control combo box drop down list.

For example, selection 1 would contain one layout of text boxes and other drop down lists, selection 2 would have its own layout and selection 3 its own.

The ways I currently can think of would be to either have a script unhide cells containing the different layouts, i.e. on selection one show the cells with layout 1, on selection 2 show other cells containing layout 2 and so on. Alternatively I can only think of having VBA code deleting everything in the sheet and rebuilding it with the desired layout every time I change selection in the combo box. Both of these options feel like they would very quickly become laggy as I add more things in to the respective setups, none the less I can't really think of other options (lets just pretend having separate sheets for each layout is not an option).

Does anyone know a better way and if so, how?

If not, which one of these would be the best to use if we consider that there would be quite a lot of textboxes, format controls and design in the separate layouts?

And finally, how do I actually get this to work, currently I'm for some reason not getting my VBA code to work to actually perform actions when i choose different options in the combo box?

So far my code have looked like

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    

   If ws.DropDowns(2) = "Option1" Then
       ws.Rows(rowVal & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
   End If
End Sub
```

This is obviously just a test to see if i can get it to just clear cells from row 45 and downwards when changing the value in the combo box, but even that is not working.

Comment: What kind of dropdown are you using (Forms/ActiveX/Data Validation)?  Is your drop-down linked to a cell?  Is the code in the worksheet code module?

Comment: Currenttly trying things mainly with forms/ActiveX. The code provided previously was put in the sheets code module in the vba-window. The idea has been to have the dropdown linked to a cell on another sheet, and when the value change in that cell the script runs.

Im not married to one type or the other, the main goal  is to have the sheet alter severely in appearance and what objects are shown depending on what option is picked in a drop-down list, other than that anything kind of goes, prefferable as lag-free as possible.